# Jax-RS /cxf random empty response

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I have an resource JAX-RS which should return picture from url. 
it works well, but sometimes the response is empty for the same url with an http 200 code.

how can i fix this, thank's

httpd logs :

```
100.xx.xx.xx - - [11/Jun/2020:16:27:46 +0200] [GET /ressources/1000/1 HTTP/1.1] 200 - [http://r-dev.fr/] [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0]
100.xx.xx.xx - - [11/Jun/2020:16:27:46 +0200] [GET /ressources/1000/1 HTTP/1.1] 200 - [http://r-dev.fr/] [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0]
```

```
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-m10</version>
            </dependency>   
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

```
    public Response getPicture(final String url) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
        try {

            Response r = client.get();
            if (r.getStatusInfo().getStatusCode() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                String contentDispo = r.getStringHeaders().getFirst("Content-Disposition");
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(contentDispo)) {
                    ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition(contentDispo);
                    String fileName = cd.getParameter("filename");
                    String mimeType = defineMimeType(fileName);
                    Object entity = r.getEntity();
                    return Response.ok(entity, mimeType).header("Connection", "Keep-Alive").header("Keep-Alive", "timeout=60, max=100").build();
                } else {
                    return Response.serverError().build();
                }
            } else {
                return r;
            }
        } catch (WebApplicationException | ClientException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException();
        }
    }
```

Api to get image from url with method :

```
 public Response getRessource(String idRessource) {    File fileToReturn = ....
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(new FileInputStream(fileToReturn)).type("application/octet-stream")
    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileToReturn.getName()).build();  
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Erreur : le fichier d'id {} est introuvable", idRessource, e);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I have no reproducible case since it is random. I can send you more information if necessary. I'm looking for suggestions to analyze the problem

Comment: Depending on which URL you are requesting and what the response of that URL is returning, it might be that `r.getEntity()` simply returns `null` or an empty string, which is passed back to the caller of `getPicture()`.

Comment: the response is empty for the same url, Url is an internal link for another project.

Comment: Not exactly sure what to expect. When you request an URL with `WebClient.create(url)` and that URL is returning an empty body, then you are returning an empty body in your `getPicture()` call as well.

Comment: when i request an url with webclient.create(url), the method getRessources is called. for the same url, getRessource return empty response. I don't return an empty body. can there be a problem where multiple acces to the same ressouce ( access with fileinputstream) ?

Comment: It might be that the file you are trying to load in `getRessource()` is simply empty. You might want to check the file size you are requesting and add more logger entries to debug the issue.

Comment: the file is not empty. the response contains a status, metadata and the entity. The metadata contains the following information:

   Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Keep-Alive=[timeout=15, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive]